# Keyboard Shortcuts: Set F1-F12 as shortcut without key combination

Tags: settings, keyboard-shortcuts

Just migrated from ubuntu 19.04 to elementary and loving it!

One major problem with keyboard shortcuts on elementary is that to set a shortcut for say MUTE (icon listed on F6 Key) i have to use a keyboard combination in settings: Ex - Super + F6. simply pressing f6 to setup a shortcut for mute doesn't work - says - disabled.

This is something that works very well in Ubuntu! (and might force me to move back)

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorted by installing Dconf-editor.

All the custom keyboard shortcuts settings are stored in the dconf database.

You can easily access them with dconf-editor:

sudo apt-get install dconf-editor

Then go to the following dconf path in the editor:

/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/

and change manually!